# How to get the name management on excel by visual studio?

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the name management on excel 2010 by visual studio.
What's the function or code can be use on visual studio by VB?
i.g I have a name called "JOB" by name management, what's function or property can get "JOB" on visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

I find the way what I looking for!

`workbook.Names("JOB").RefersToRange.Value = "goodJob"`

The Cell which is named "JOB" in Excel gotta be "goodJob".